# How to get work the hook_form?

Tags: hooks

I try to hook the node form by hook_form(), but I can't modify the base form.
I try to do this like below

```
function products_form($node, &$form_state) {
  $type = node_type_get_type($node);

  $form['title'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => check_plain($type->title_label),
    '#default_value' => !empty($node->title) ? $node->title : '',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#weight' => -5,
  );
  return $form;
}
```

What's is wrong? My module name is 'products'.

Answer (score 1):

[`hook_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_form/7) is only meant to be used by a module that provide content type:

> This hook, **implemented by node modules**, is called to retrieve the form that is displayed to create or edit a node. This form is displayed at path node/add/[node type] or node/[node ID]/edit.

Emphasis mine.

It provides the form, and does not do alterations.

If you want *to modify base form* created by another module, you need [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7):

> Perform alterations before a form is rendered.
>
> One popular use of this hook is to **add form elements to the node form**. When altering a node form, the node object can be accessed at $form['#node'].

Again, emphasis mine.